# How to hide the mouse pointer with pyAutoGUI?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Is there a way to hide the mouse pointer with pyAutoGUI?

```py
import time
import pyautogui


pyautogui.hidePointer()

time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.showPointer()
```

If not, is there another way to hide the mouse pointer with another library or in plain python, perhaps with the `os` module?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you can actually "hide" the mouse using Python or else the user wouldn't be able to use the mouse. But, what you could do is hide the mouse at the edge of the screen because on most screens if you move the mouse to the edge of the screen it hides the mouse. So, all you would have to do is move the mouse to the side of the screen. The code would be something like this:

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.moveTo(1919, 511) # change this to the position of the edge of your screen

time.sleep(5)
# show the mouse back on the screen
pyautogui.moveTo(1736, 617) # change this to the coordinates you want
```

To find out the position of your mouse use this code:

```
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()
    print(currentMouseX, currentMouseY)
    time.sleep(1)
```

and move your mouse to the edge of the screen. The coordinates that got printed   you should change with `1919, 511` and `1736, 617`.